# About rowspace and nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

For 
$$A =
\left(
\begin{array}{}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1  
\end{array}
\right)
$$
write any vector $x$ such that $x = x_{rowspace} + x_{nullspace}$, where $x=\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$.

I know that:
$x_{rowspace} = w\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $w,x \in \mathbb{R}$

$x_{nullspace} = y\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + z\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $

However, I do not know how to answer the question. Particularly, I do not know the relationship of a, b, c, and d, with w, x, y, and z.

Comment: Note that $a=w+y$ and $c=w-y$.  Adding these gives $a+c=2w$, so if you know the $a$ and $c$ that you want to have, you can figure out what value of $w$ is needed to accomplish that.  Do so similarly to find the remaining values.

Comment: So it seems to be you want to see the matrix's rows as vectors in $\;\Bbb R^4\;$,  and then *any vector* $\;x\;$ actually means *any vector* $\;x\in\Bbb R^4\;$ , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a desired $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$, we wish to find coefficients $w,x,y,z$ such that:

$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=w\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+x\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}w+y\\x+z\\w-y\\x-z\end{bmatrix}$

Two matrices are equal if and only if each corresponding entry are equal.

That is to say, these imply the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} a = w+y\\ b=x+z\\ c=w-y\\ d=x-z\end{cases}$$

As $a,b,c,d$ are known and $w,x,y,z$ are unknown, we try to write each unknown in terms of the knowns.  We do so via gaussian elimination.

Finding $w$: by adding the first and third line of the system of equations, we arrive at $a+c=2w$ implying that $w=\frac{a+c}{2}$

Do so similarly for the other unknowns.

That is, we learn that we can write $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ as $(\frac{a+c}{2})\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + (\star\star)\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Describe the (rows') nullspace explicitly (by now it must be clear that its dimension is two):

$$\text{Second row}:\;\;y+w=0\implies y=-w\;,\;\;\text{First row}:\;\;x+z=0\implies  x=-z\implies$$

basis for the null space:

$$\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\\!-1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\!-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Now check these two vectors together with the obvious ones you already have for the row space are indeed linarly independent and thus a basis of $\;\Bbb R^4\;$, so we can write now

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\!-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\delta\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\\!-1\end{pmatrix}$$

You get the system

$$\begin{cases}I\;\;&\alpha+\gamma=a\\II\;\;&\beta+\delta=b\\III\;\;&\alpha-\gamma=c\\IV\;\;&\beta-\delta=d\end{cases}$$

Now just check this systems *always* has solution no matter what $\;a,b,c,d\;$ , for example:

$$I+III \implies \alpha=\frac{a+c}2\implies\gamma=\frac{a-c}2\;,\;\;\text{etc.}$$